# Create a buy function off an ID

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I have a python script that generates a random "user", "price", and "id". Now I want to be able to buy one of the users using the id. I tried to append a list and index into it, but that got me a bit confused and didn't work. Below is my draft python script

```py
import random 
import string

inventory = []
money = 25

def removeFromInventory(itemname, itemvalue):
    print(null)

def addToInventory(itemname, itemvalue):
    print(null)
    
def listOffers(budget):
    if budget > money:
        print("You cant afford your budget")
    else:
        for a in range(10):
            uid = str(str(random.randint(1,10)) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
            user = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(random.randint(3,4)))
            print("User:" + str(user) + " ID:" + str(uid) + " Price:" + str(random.randint(5, budget)))
    
def purchaseUser(inventory, itemId, cash=money):
    ival = inventory[itemId].get("value")
    iname = inventory[itemId].get("itemname")
    subPrice = ival *.3 + ival
    total = subPrice * .25 + subPrice
    
    if cash < total:
        print("Error: Insufficient Funds")
    else:
        addtoInventory(iname, ival)
```

Desired behavior:
`Create a user, price, and id at random` Like so: `{"User": "axf", "Price": 10, "ID": "1a"}`

Comment: Are "user" and "price" supposed to be the same thing as "itemname" and "value"?

Comment: Yes, although that is just printing that data so I didn't know if I need to stick with the same ones.

Comment: and is "inventory" supposed to be the store inventory, or the list of things you've purchased?  It looks like your code is trying to use it for both things at once.

Comment: store inventory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
from collections import Counter
import random
import string
from typing import Dict, NamedTuple, NewType


ItemId = NewType('ItemId', str)


class Item(NamedTuple):
    id: ItemId
    name: str
    price: int


all_items: Dict[ItemId, Item] = {}
inventory: Dict[ItemId, int] = Counter()
money = 25


def remove_from_inventory(id: ItemId) -> None:
    inventory[id] -= 1


def add_to_inventory(id: ItemId) -> None:
    inventory[id] += 1


def list_offers(budget: int) -> None:
    if budget > money:
        print("You cant afford your budget")
        return

    for _ in range(10):
        item_id = ItemId(
            str(random.randint(1, 10))
            + random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        )
        item_name = ''.join(
            random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
            for _ in range(random.randint(3, 4))
        )
        item_price = random.randint(5, budget)
        print(f"Item: {item_name} ID: {item_id} Price: {item_price}")
        # Collisions are unlikely but possible!  Consider the uuid module.
        all_items[item_id] = Item(item_id, item_name, item_price)


def purchase_item(item_id: ItemId, cash: int = money) -> None:
    item = all_items[item_id]
    total_price = item.price * 1.3 * 1.25
    if cash < total_price:
        print("Error: Insufficient Funds")
        return

    print(f"Buying {item.name} for a total price of {total_price}")
    add_to_inventory(item_id)
```

The general idea is to store your items in a dictionary where the id is the key.  Once you have that dictionary (which I've named `all_items`), you can simply use the id to refer to each item rather than needing to provide its name and value; I've implemented the `inventory` here as a counter that tracks the number of each item (by its `ItemId`) rather than a list of items.

Comment: Life saver thanks so much